# Implement Stack using Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, output

I have made this code to implement stack by linked list with some operations like add elements, delete, etc. There's some issue with my output, which is unexpected. If you can modify the freeStack(),pop() and push() functions, feel free to modify them. Thanks

```
// C program for linked list implementation of stack 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

// Implement a stack as a linked list
typedef struct Node { 
    int data; 
    struct StackNode* next; 
}Node; 

typedef struct Stack {
    int size;
    Node *pTop;
}Stack;

// Initialize the stack
void init (Stack *s) {
    s = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    s->size = 0;
    s->pTop = NULL;
}

// Check if a stack is empty
int isEmpty (Stack st) {
    return (st.size == 0);
}

// Push operation to add new element
int push (int newData, Stack *st) 
{
// put newData in a stack node -> this node becomes the top element
    Node *p = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (p == NULL) // check if memory allocation for the new node is successful
        return 0; // return 0 to indicate failure
    p->data = newData;
    p->next = st->pTop;
    st->pTop = p;
    st->size++;
    return 1;
}

// Pop operation to delete the first top element
int pop (Stack *st) 
{
    Node *p;
    if (isEmpty(*st))
        return 0; // fail to pop
    p = st->pTop;
    st->pTop = st->pTop->next; // change the pointer of the top element to the second top element
    st->size--;
    free(p);
    return 1;
}

// Top operation to return the top element
int top(Stack st) {
    if (isEmpty(st))
        return 1;
    return st.pTop->data;
}

// Display elements of the stack
void display(Stack *s)
{
    Node *p = s->pTop;
    printf("Stack: ");
    for (; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
        printf("%d ", p->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

// Free all memory used by the stack
void freeStack(Stack* st) {
    Node* current = st->pTop;
    Node* next;

    while (current != NULL) {
        next = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }

    st->pTop = NULL;
    st->size = 0;
}

int main() 
{ 
    // Memory allocation
    Stack st;
    init(&st);

    // Push elements
    push(10, &st); 
    push(20, &st); 
    push(30, &st); 
    display(&st);

    printf("30 is popped from stack\n", pop(&st)); 
    display(&st);

    printf("Top element is %d\n", top(st)); 

    freeStack(&st);

    return 0; 
}
```

Here's the output:

```
linked_list_stack.c: In function 'push':
linked_list_stack.c:36:17: warning: assignment to 'struct StackNode *' from incompatible pointer type 'Node *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   36 |         p->next = st->pTop;
      |                 ^
linked_list_stack.c: In function 'pop':
linked_list_stack.c:50:14: warning: assignment to 'Node *' from incompatible pointer type 'struct StackNode *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   50 |     st->pTop = st->pTop->next; // change the pointer of the top element to the second top element
      |              ^
linked_list_stack.c: In function 'display':
linked_list_stack.c:68:25: warning: assignment to 'Node *' from incompatible pointer type 'struct StackNode *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   68 |     for (; p != NULL; p = p->next) {
      |                         ^
linked_list_stack.c: In function 'freeStack':
linked_list_stack.c:80:14: warning: assignment to 'Node *' from incompatible pointer type 'struct StackNode *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   80 |         next = current->next;
      |              ^
Stack: 30 20 10 -489483407
30 is popped from stack
Stack: 20 10 -489483407
Top element is 20
```

Comment: What is `struct StackNode`? There is no declaration of it

Comment: ***One*** of your problems is one common for beginners: You forget that function arguments are passed *by value*. That means, the value used in the call is *copied* into the functions local argument variables. The life-time of those local argument variables are like any other local function variable, and last only until the end of the function. When the function returns, all modifications you have made to those variables are lost. So think about that and what happens in e.g. the `init` function and the assignment to `s`.

Comment: And you should really treat any and all warning messages as *errors*. You're doing some bad things in your code, which are allowed by the C standard, but are not good and the compiler tries to tell you that.

Comment: Regarding the `init` function, when I look at how it's called then you don't need the `malloc` call. The pointer `s` already points to an allocated structure object. Please take some time to refresh the chapters in your beginners books about pointers and dynamic allocation and the pointer-to operator `&`.

Comment: @0___________ , `StackNode` should be `Node`. It is most probably a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler does not know what the `struct StackNode` is. You need to:

```
typedef struct StackNode { 
    int data; 
    struct StackNode* next; 
}Node;
```

Also, I do not have an idea what you tried to archive. Return reference to allocated struct.

```
// Initialize the stack
Stack *init (void) {
    Stack *s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
    if(s)
    {
       s->size = 0;
       s->pTop = NULL;
    }
    return s;
}
```

In `main` function:

```
    Stack *st;
    st = init();
    if(st)
    {
         push(10, st); 
         /* ... */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pop` function should return the data field of the top node, not just 1 as posted.